# Add parameters to @beforeclass dynamically in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

I need to add Parameters to **@BeforeClass** method with **TestNG** Class.
I'm **running a TestSuite dynamically** with this code:

```
List<XmlSuite> suites = getXmlTestSuiteForUI(xmlName);

TestNG testNG = new TestNG();

testNG.setXmlSuites(suites);
testNG.setPreserveOrder(true);
testNG.addListener(testListenerAdapter);

testNG.run();
```

*How can I add parameters to the @BeforeClass Method??*

Somethig like this but instead of test.setParameters something like beforeclass.addParameters.

```
for (XmlSuite suite : suites){
    for(XmlTest test : suite.getTests()){
        test.setParameters(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you already have a `@Parameters` on your `@BeforeClass` method or not? Maybe you should give a snippet of your test.

Comment: Yes I have it, but I can't access to the method to add the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **solution** is adding parameters into suite.

```
for (XmlSuite suite : suites) {
    suite.setParameters(parameters);
}
```

**Test.class**

```
@BeforeClass
@Parameters({"accountID"})
public void tearUp(String accountID) throws Exception {
    super.tearUp(Integer.valueOf(accountID));
}
```

Comment: It is working too. Like `setParameters` on test or class, it depends on what you want to do. For example, on suite, you won't be able to run the same test with different parameters.

Answer (score 1):

`setParameters` is available on `XmlClass` too.

```
for (XmlSuite suite : suites) {
    for(XmlTest test : suite.getTests()) {
        for(XmlClass clazz : test.getXmlClasses()) {
            clazz.setParameters(params);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter in the class is tagging by any annotation? Where?